# How to fix Gateway Timeout on AWS Lightsail server?

Tags: php, codeigniter, bitnami, ubuntu-server, amazon-lightsail

I have created a codeigniter app on a AWS with Lightsail that queries a large amount of data from an old magento database, converts into a new format, and pushes it to my new database.

The app works well and fine on my local machine under localhost, but when deploying to a AWS, I encounter a Gateway Timeout error. I believe this is because my local server is willing to wait longer for a response from another server than my AWS.

Is there any way to solve this error? Or rather, is there any way I can increase the amount of time my AWS is willing to wait for a response from my server database?

I tried this, but no dice:

```
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ob_implicit_flush(TRUE);
ob_end_flush();
```

I also tried this to no avail:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Both were placed in the constructor for my model. If either of these solutions do work, was that the wrong place to put the code?

EDIT: I should also mention that this is a Bitnami server running in Ubuntu.

Comment: As you kind of assumed, the issue is with the AWS configuration, whilst I can't point you in the direction as I am unfamiliar with lightsail, the issue will be with its load balancer or reverse proxy, which times out before the application (your php) has finished.

Comment: @Scuzzy You're right, but how to I edit the load balancer on a ubuntu server, then?

Comment: That's a job for another stack network, stack overflow focus is on on code problems, like a devops or a infrastructure site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future generations, you need to edit timeout in the php-fpm-apache.conf. This is on the line

```
<Proxy "unix:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/www.sock|fcgi://www-fpm" timeout=900>
```

If you don't know where that is, just use

```
sudo find / -iname php-fpm-apache.conf
```

in the console. Mine happened to be located at /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/

Be sure to restart apache and php-fpm with

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart php-fpm
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

And you'll be good to go!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was seeing my "Remaining CPU burst capacity" graph reach zero.

The solution (found [here](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/how-to-create-larger-instance-from-snapshot-using-console)) was to create a bigger size instance. To do this, create a snapshot, then on the snapshot select "create new instance", and choose a bigger size than I was using.

Then, as quoted from [this blog](https://metablogue.com/upgrade-aws-lightsail-server-wordpress/)

> Once done, go to your static IP and edit it to point to a new instance rather than the old instance.

That fixed it for me.